# How static files works in express js?

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I am developing a express.js app. I am developing admin and users two routes. But in admin section I created sub directories like post, media, etc. I want to use static files like style sheet for post, media, etc.

/admin/posts/js/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js 404 92.978 ms - 19288

where this file locate in
/admin/js/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js

I put all stylesheet and javascripts file in public/admin/. and I want use this stylesheet for all sub directories like posts, media, feedback, etc

```
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine static files with dynamically generated content using Express. For example you can default to serving static content, then serve dynamic content for some routes. e.g.

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('./'));
app.get('/info', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ status: 'OK', timeStamp: new Date() });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Static Root</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4 class="center">I am static content!</h4>
    </body>
</html>
```

You'd serve this initially from one folder with index.js and index.html.
Any route other than /info will look for static files, e.g. / or /index.html will pull index.html.

You can easily add stylesheets for example, in a ./stylesheets folder

e.g.

**/stylesheets/test.css**

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
    color: green;
}
```

This is then referenced by index.html